# Android - Dynamically load system library without exact path?

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries

A couple months ago I graduated from Android samples to work-related projects. As such, I am still painfully new to this build system and fully admit my inexperience with all things *.mk file and Android related.

I have a library that depends on OpenCL v1 or greater. Loading is delayed until the functionality is needed, and only if the minimum version of OpenCL is supported. Up until a couple days ago, I would receive a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` whenever I tried to load it because `libGLES_mali.so` could not be located. Apparently the device my coworker tested on had this file while my device does not. I found other GLES libs that do exist on my test phone but my code to load them is... longer than I would think it should be.

Trying to use `System.loadLibrary("GLES")` didn't yield success, nor anything similar.

According to this site (http://www.2net.co.uk/tutorial/android-egl-cgf-is-dead) I need to try to load every GLES library I can think of by name, from both `system/lib/` and `system/lib/egl/`.  Consequently, currently my code for loading this library is as follows:

```
boolean bGles = false;


        if(!bGles) {
            try {
                System.load("system/lib/egl/libGLES.so");
                bGles = true;
            } catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            }
        }

        if(!bGles) {
            try {
                System.load("system/lib/libGLES.so");
                bGles = true;
            } catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            }
        }
        if(!bGles) {
            try {
                System.load("system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so");
                bGles = true;
            } catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            }
        }
        if(!bGles) {
            try {
                System.load("system/lib/libGLESv1_CM.so");
                bGles = true;
            } catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            }
        }
        if(!bGles) {
            try {
                System.load("system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM.so");
                bGles = true;
            } catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            }
        }
```

It's so terribly messy! Is there no way of asking Android to load whatever the default 'GLES' is on the system? Default version number? I can't knock the tutorial completely, as all my libraries now load and function correctly now, but what will I do for other devices? With *other* names for their GLES libs?

I feel that I must be misunderstanding the article. Certainly, there must be a better way to load a shared system library than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there's a better way to do what you're doing

```
String libraries[] = {"name1","name2",...}
boolean success = false;
for(String library : libraries) {
  try{
    System.load(library);
    success = true;
    break;
  }
  catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError) {}
}
if(!success) {
   //Handle the failed all case
}
```

Secondly-  why do you think you need to do this to begin with?  Why aren't you using the build in OpenGL functionality and Java classes?  If you aren't, your app is likely to break badly between devices.  Edit:   Ok, I now noticed OpenCL and did some digging.  Android does not support OpenCL.  Some devices do, but there's no general libraries for it.  I'd reconsider going this route, if you do follow it you will only ever work on a subset of devices, and you're going to have to add hacks for each new generation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was given this project a couple months ago and up until a week ago, was only making cosmetic changes to the GUI. So to answer 'why', all I can say is, 'to avoid exceptions'. The native library that I am delay-loading throws an exception if I *don't* try to load the GLES lib explicitly. I really don't know anything about the OpenGL functionality already present, but our application must absolutely use the native lib that depends on GLES.

Comment: Sounds like you got put in kind of a shitty position.  Google said in 2013 that they have no plans to support OpenCL, and they haven't seems to change their position.  OpenGL is supported and built in, of course.  If you're using device level hacks you can get CL on some but not all devices.  I think your best bet is to look for a library that keeps up to date on the hacks you need, but I don't know of any at the moment.  You may want to look into what needs OpenCL and if it can be refactored out of your project long term.